# How to specify wildcards for api paths in AspNetCoreRateLimit configuration?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, throttling, rate-limiting

I'm using AspNetCoreRateLimit in .net core 3 web api application. I was hoping that there is a way to use wildcards in a path to limit all requests that match the path to a certain number.
Here is my (incorrect) configuration in appsettings:

```
  "ClientRateLimiting": {
    "EnableEndpointRateLimiting": true,
    "StackBlockedRequests": false,
    "ClientIdHeader": "X-ClientId",
    "HttpStatusCode": 429,
    "QuotaExceededMessage": "System is busy, please try again later",
    "GeneralRules": [
      {
        "Endpoint": "get:/api/*",
        "Period": "10s",
        "Limit": 3
      },
    ]
  }
```

Unfortunately with the above configuration each unique url that matches the endpoint pattern can be executed 3 times in 10 seconds. For example, api/test/foo, api/test1/foo, and api/test2/foo will be allowed to execute concurrently 3 times in 10 seconds - i.e. 9 requests in total per 10 seconds.

Is there a way to configure the limiter to limit all requests matching the pattern to a single number? That is, I'd like to make sure that only 3 requests that match the pattern could execute in 10 seconds.

Comment: Did you find an approach for this? I am also looking for an answer to this.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used this library but looking at the documentation, you have this sentence.

> If EnableEndpointRateLimiting is set to false, then the limits will
> apply globally and only the rules that have as endpoint * will apply.
> For example if you set a limit of 5 calls per second, any HTTP call to
> any endpoint will count towards that limit. [source](https://github.com/stefanprodan/AspNetCoreRateLimit/wiki/ClientRateLimitMiddleware#setup)

So, your code becomes like this.

```
  "ClientRateLimiting": {
    "EnableEndpointRateLimiting": false,
    "StackBlockedRequests": false,
    "ClientIdHeader": "X-ClientId",
    "HttpStatusCode": 429,
    "QuotaExceededMessage": "System is busy, please try again later",
    "GeneralRules": [
      {
        "Endpoint": "*",
        "Period": "10s",
        "Limit": 3
      },
    ]
  }
```

emphasis on these two lines.

```
    "EnableEndpointRateLimiting": false,
    "Endpoint": "*",
```

Of course, to make this work, you will have to have a separate API Service, perhaps a micro service, that only contains the group of API endpoints to which you want this specific rule to apply.

I suggest this not as a final solution, but as a possible solution, because, if you are married to this specific package, it does not current support (I went through the documentation again to be sure) the scenario you are looking.

Comment: Your suggestion is not going to work because if EnableEndpointRageLimiting is set to true then Endpoint must be set to *. This is clearly stated in the documentation that you quoted. When I initially looked at the library I also assumed that "only the rules that have as endpoint * " was applicable to rules that contained *. However, the rule must be "Endpoint": " * " - i.e. cannot contain any partial paths.

Comment: yeah, I have udpated my answer based on what you pointed out. I am afraid, it is another solution you may not like, but, if I were you in a similar situation and i HAVE to do something like this, with this package only, then, I would go down this route